# Running .bsh error (ZereneStacker)

Tags: bash, shell-script, chrome-os, chrome-book

I am trying to run the program ZereneStacker on Linux (I am using a Chromebook Samsung 3). I downloaded the program's .zip from [here](http://zerenesystems.com/cms/stacker/docs/linux_installation_instructions) and extracted it. According to that download page, the .zip file includes:

```
ZereneStacker          executable launcher

ZereneStacker.bsh      launch script (provided for backward compatibility)
```

After extraction, I `cd`'d into the extracted folder `ZereneStacker` tried the commands

```
sudo chmod +x ZereneStacker
sudo ./ZereneStacker
```

and

```
sudo chmod +x ZereneStacker.bsh
sudo ./ZereneStacker.bsh
```

For both the output was long and included the following:

```
Fatal error: /home/user/ZereneStacker/jre/bin/java exists but is not an executable file
```

Do I need to change permissions further? Am I missing  installation steps or should it install on first execution?

---

*Here is the full output in case it is helpful:*

```
sizeof(ptr) = 8
Physical memory = 2986188800
isSafeMode = 0
argv[0] = [/home/user/ZereneStacker/ZereneStacker]
launcherFile = [/home/user/ZereneStacker/ZereneStacker]
sigh... appdir = /home/user/ZereneStacker
arg0 = /home/user/ZereneStacker/ZereneStacker
argc = 1
endDir = /ZereneStacker
length = 33
argsLength = 0
appdir = /home/user/ZereneStacker
appdataName = /root/.ZereneStacker
appdataName = /root/.ZereneStacker
appdataZSName = /root/.ZereneStacker
configFileName = /root/.ZereneStacker/zerenstk.cfg
configFile = 0
mxStringFromConfig = 

mxString = -Xmx1024m
launchCmdFileName = /root/.ZereneStacker/zerenstk.launchcmd
launchOKFileName = /root/.ZereneStacker/zerenstk.launchOK
trying launchParamsFileName = /home/user/ZereneStacker/zerenstk.ini
initialization line = "{appdir}/jre/bin/java" {memsize} -DjavaBits={javaBits} -Dlaunchcmddir="{launchcmddir}" -classpath "{appdir}/ZereneStacker.jar:{appdir}/JREextensions/*" com.zerenesystems.stacker.gui.MainFrame

invocation line before possible tweaking = "/home/user/ZereneStacker/jre/bin/java" -Xmx1024m -DjavaBits=64bitJava -Dlaunchcmddir="/root/.ZereneStacker" -classpath "/home/user/ZereneStacker/ZereneStacker.jar:/home/user/ZereneStacker/JREextensions/*" com.zerenesystems.stacker.gui.MainFrame
argument 0 before tweaking: [/home/user/ZereneStacker/jre/bin/java]
argument 1 before tweaking: [-Xmx1024m]
argument 2 before tweaking: [-DjavaBits=64bitJava]
argument 3 before tweaking: [-Dlaunchcmddir=/root/.ZereneStacker]
argument 4 before tweaking: [-classpath]
argument 5 before tweaking: [/home/user/ZereneStacker/ZereneStacker.jar:/home/user/ZereneStacker/JREextensions/*]
argument 6 before tweaking: [com.zerenesystems.stacker.gui.MainFrame]
argument 7 before tweaking: [(null)]
Invocation line: ["/home/user/ZereneStacker/jre/bin/java" -Xmx1024m -DjavaBits=64bitJava -Dlaunchcmddir="/root/.ZereneStacker" -classpath "/home/user/ZereneStacker/ZereneStacker.jar:/home/user/ZereneStacker/JREextensions/*" com.zerenesystems.stacker.gui.MainFrame ]
statbuf.st_mode = 100644
Fatal error: /home/user/ZereneStacker/jre/bin/java exists but is not an executable file
```

Comment: The [FAQ](http://zerenesystems.com/cms/stacker/docs/faqlist#how_do_i_download_and_install_the_program) on their website says this:

"For...Linux, the downloaded file is a self-contained bundle that does not need to be “installed”. Just put it anywhere you like, typically either on your Desktop or in your Applications folder.

The first time you run Zerene Stacker, it will go through a short process of configuring memory allocation based on what type of computer you have and how much physical memory it has installed. After this is done, the program will automatically restart..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from ZereneStacker support, I figured out the following solution:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo chmod +x ZereneStacker/*.zslinux
sudo chmod +x ZereneStacker/ZereneStacker.bsh
sudo chmod +x ZereneStacker/ZereneStacker
sudo chmod +x ZereneStacker/jre/bin/*
cd ZereneStacker
./ZereneStacker.bsh
```

This solution with `openjdk-8-jdk` worked even though Zerene Stacker has built-in `10.0.1 JRE`. I only tried with `openjdk-8-jdk`